# Remove words from string contained in array

Tags: php

I have an array 
`$c=array("ok","and","or")`
and a `$str="i am ok and fine"`
now i want to strip $str from $c array elements so that `$str="i am fine"`
how can i do this?

Comment: `$result = str_replace($c,'',$str);` for a simplistic character removal, else use `preg_replace()`

Comment: `$result=
str_replace($c,'',
$str);`
tried this but also removes single characters present in word.

Comment: That's why I said `simplistic` in my comments; so if you specifically want `words` use preg_replace and modify your words array to include `word boundaries`..... when asking a question here, it always helps if you say what you've already tried, and why it didn't work for you

Comment: How do ya include word boundaries?

Comment: `\b` is the regular expression indicator for a word boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here.  One is the editing of the string to remove the words you've mentioned.  The other is the manipulation of the string to handle it word by word. If you just do character replacement you get extra spaces.

So try something like this. Not debugged.

```
$q = explode(' ',$str);    /* turn string into list of words */
$r = array();
foreach ($q as $w) {       /* check the words */
  if (!in_array($w,$c)) {
    $r[] = $w;
  }
}
$str = implode(' ',$r);   /* turn new list of words back into string */
```